# Does a library exist to compute the area under a curve in jqPlot?

Tags: jqplot

Is this already contained within `jqPlot`, or does a library exist that would do this?

I'm sure I could figure it out if I put 12 hours in, but I just figured I'd ask. :)

Comment: Any progress in this field yet?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such a feature in jqPlot but sure you can use math to find the area under the curve by giving x,y coordinates. Just google for integration methods.